# Join Elements Between Columns According to an Index

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

There is a manual process done to combine elements from a table, when you want to create a more global set. The idea is to use pandas tools to make it easy and more autonomous.

Lets consider the next example, where you have the next table with information about some universities and the students who have a great performance on each semester, during the fourth semester of a Master. As you can see there are some "nan" values.

```
        1 Semester   2 Semester    3 Semester   4 Semester
Harvard    Oliver        nan         Michael       nan
MIT         Noah         Connor      Callum      George
            Jack          nan          nan        Oscar
Stanford    Harry         nan          Kyle        nan
            Liam          nan         Reece        nan
Georgia     Jake         Charlie       nan         nan
            Jacob        Damian        nan         nan
            Mason        Daniel        nan         nan
```

The idea is to show the table per master, so you need to join each one of the semesters and create a single one column as shown in the next table

```
           Master
Harvard    Oliver
           Michael
  MIT       Noah
            Jack
            Connor
            Callum
            George
            Oscar
Stanford    Harry
            Liam
            Kyle
            Reece
 Georgia    Jake
            Jacob
            Mason
           Charlie
            Damian
            Daniel
```

I have tried with many options like merge, join and concatenate but none of one have worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/home/datasci/PEC/prog_datasci_4/data/university.csv')

sub_table= data[['university','1_semester','2_semester',  
'3_semester','4_semester']]

retri = sub_table.set_index('university')

location_battle = 
retri.astype(str).groupby(['university','1_semester','2_semester',  
'3_semester','4_semester'])
```

My goal is to join the columns of the first table (semester 1,2,3,4) and create a single column, not considering the "nan" values

Comment: `df.set_index('university').stack().dropna()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for new columns [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/datasci/PEC/prog_datasci_4/data/university.csv')

cols = ['1 Semester','2 Semester', '3 Semester','4 Semester']
df1 = (df.set_index('university')[cols]
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('University')
        .reset_index(name='Master'))
print (df1)
   University   Master
0     Harvard   Oliver
1     Harvard  Michael
2         MIT     Noah
3         MIT   Connor
4         MIT   Callum
5         MIT   George
6         MIT     Jack
7         MIT    Oscar
8    Stanford    Harry
9    Stanford     Kyle
10   Stanford     Liam
11   Stanford    Reece
12    Georgia     Jake
13    Georgia  Charlie
14    Georgia    Jacob
15    Georgia   Damian
16    Georgia    Mason
17    Georgia   Daniel
```

If need first column in index:

```
cols = ['1 Semester','2 Semester', '3 Semester','4 Semester']
df2 = (df.set_index('university')[cols]
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .to_frame('Master'))
print (df2)
             Master
university         
Harvard      Oliver
Harvard     Michael
MIT            Noah
MIT          Connor
MIT          Callum
MIT          George
MIT            Jack
MIT           Oscar
Stanford      Harry
Stanford       Kyle
Stanford       Liam
Stanford      Reece
Georgia        Jake
Georgia     Charlie
Georgia       Jacob
Georgia      Damian
Georgia       Mason
Georgia      Daniel
```